# How can I troubleshoot my Macbook freezing for 5-10 seconds several times each day?

Tags: macos, mac, freeze

I just got a 2017 MacBook. It's imaged with my company's IT image before it was handed off to me. Not a ton of bloat on it at all, but worth mentioning.

Since I got it, I've noticed that when I'm switching between applications it often will freeze for 5-15 seconds at a time. I'm not accustomed to troubleshooting Macs, so would appreciate some help. Part of me suspects it's network related; when video conferencing it seems to lock up more often. That's just a guess though.

What are some places I can look or utilities I can run to help narrow down what might be causing the lockups? When I notice a lockup, what's the Mac equivalent of Event Viewer, that I could go peak at for that time?

Answer (score -1):

(my reply is based on the Sierra software)

Firstly, back up your unique files to a place off the machine.

The IT imaging introduces every possible variable as an unknown value, so I'd start my learning from there. 
1) What did your IT have to say about what's in their imaging? Were you given notes, or a link to their Support page? Are other users experiencing the same issues? 
2) Do system software updates happen automatically, or approved before pushed to you by IT? Is everything as current as IT permits?
3)Did IT test this switching function before giving you the machine? Can they do it now, remotely?

4)Maybe there's a backup that runs when you switch apps, or some auto-caching to a server, which may be mirrored. On an new Mac, backup should easily happen in the background; again, there's a lot of unknowns within your setup.

5)Throttling of network bandwidth would cause the issues you mention if all the apps have to be newly retrieved from the server, or you are storing everything on their remote server. Or you are constantly connected via shared docs to remote users?

6)"Activity Monitor" will show you all processes and the demand on the system. You can put an icon into your Dock to find it quickly.

7)"Login Items" is a normally-editable list of what opens at startup, and may have some clues for you. System Preferences/Users and Groups/Login Items. 
8)"Extensions" from "System Preferences" under the apple menu, would have another interesting list.

9)The default mac debug would be to run "Software Update" then completely power down the mac, let it sit a few minutes, and start up. (A "cold boot" vs using "Restart" which is a warm boot, to elaborate for other readers)

That's my first pass. Please post the solution you used once you have it. I'm interested to learn!

Comment: Welcome to Super User. On this Q&A site we're looking for *answers*. Please use the comments to get more information from the OP (See [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174/271445)). Please [edit] your post to remove the questions for the OP and leave the parts that give the OP actual things to do to solve his problem. Thanks for contributing.